# Image alignment not working on my own WP theme

Tags: wordpress, image, alignment

I'm bulding my own Wordpress theme and I'm trying to align image to center or side via post editor, but it's still default aligned (left).

In editor it displays properly not on the site though.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer did not work for me, for those developing a theme from scratch who encounter the same issue, adding the following code to the themes style sheet worked for me:

```
img.alignright { float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em; }
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
img.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.alignright { float: right; }
.alignleft { float: left; }
.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Wrapping_Text_Around_Images

Comment: Thanks. It helped me!

Comment: @Nick glad it helped :)

Comment: Why wp require some extra css?

Answer (score 8):

You haven't shared your code...but you need to ensure you include [WordPress-generated classes](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes) in your theme's CSS files:

```
/* =WordPress Core
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.aligncenter,
div.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
}

a img.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

Of course, you can modify these classes as needed.

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I had noticed these classes, but wondered where the styling needed to come from. So obvious now :D

Answer (score 1):

```
img.alignright { float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em; }
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
img.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.alignright { float: right; }
.alignleft { float: left; }
.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

apply this css to get align class feature